# redirect to home page in jsp after logged in

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting to home page if user is already logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629469/redirecting-to-home-page-if-user-is-already-logged-in)

If logged in user clicks on login.jsp page then he should be automatically redirected to his home.jsp. Before authentication user goes to login.jsp and after successfully authenticated by a servlet he is redirected to home.jsp, but when again the same user clicks on login page then he should be automatically redirected to home.jsp instead of logging again, how can i do it in jsp, servlet? I am setting session from that servlet after successfully authenticated.

Any help is appreciated.