# Redirecting to home page if user is already logged in

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect to another page when already authenticated user accesses login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239925/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-when-already-authenticated-user-accesses-login-p)

If a logged in user clicks on `login.jsp` page then he should be automatically redirected to his `home.jsp`. Before authentication user goes to `login.jsp` and after successfully authenticated by a servlet (doPost) he is redirected to `home.jsp`, but when again the same user clicks on login page then he should be automatically redirected to `home.jsp` instead of logging again. How can I do it in JSP/Servlet? I am setting session from that servlet after successfully authenticated.

Before login, user clicks on `login.jsp` and goes to `doPost()` method of servlet and goes to `home.jsp`. After logged in succesfully, if user clicks again on `login.jsp` then instead of going to `login.jsp`, control should go directly to `home.jsp`. How can I do it?

If user is signed out then only after clicking `login.jsp` control will go to `login.jsp` and then `doPost()` of servlet and finally `home.jsp` will come.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this code in your login.jsp

```
if(session.getAttribute("authenticated")!=null && session.getAttribute("authenticated").equals(true))
{
   response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}
```

Comment: i need to set it before authentication?

Comment: yeah when user visits login.jsp first time and authenticates successfully then you create this attribute like this. session.setAttribute("authenticated", true);

Comment: login page is in the main home page, so after authenticated from servlet if user comes to that main home page and clicks login.jsp then will he be redirected to home.jsp ?

Comment: yeah exactly. if authenticated attribute is set to true then user will be redirected to home.jsp. one more point, once a user is logged in you need to hide the link to login.jsp

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to write this. session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); in the login.jsp or i need to write something extra?

Comment: you need to write session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); after you authenticate the user. i guess you are doing authentication in servlet, so do there.

Comment: ya i am authenticating by a servlet, so after successfully authentication i will write: session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); response.sendRedirect("home.jsp"); in that servlet? or i will write session.setAttribute("authenticated", true);  in login.jsp page? But in this login.jsp page how can i create session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); if that user has not been logged in?

Comment: in the servlet code, when user is logged in successfully, write session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); and redirect to home.jsp....if user clicks on login.jsp then he/she will be redirected to home.jsp because authenticated attribute is true now.

Comment: thanks i am doing it let's see..

Comment: friend it is not working, i have written  session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); in servlet doPost method and after logged in if i am clicking on login.jsp link then again i am coming to login.jsp page and after giving username and password control is going to servlet then home.jsp. Any help?

Comment: make sure if(session.getAttribute("authenticated").equals("true")) this if statement is true in login.jsp otherwise code will not work.

Comment: ya i am writing..hope it will work

Comment: @KashifKhan: if he uses session.setAttribute("authenticated", true), and if(session.getAttribute("authenticated").equals("true")), this won't work. a String and a Boolean will never be equal.

Comment: @JBNizet yup you are right. I have updated my answer. if statement should be like if(session.getAttribute("authenticated"))

Comment: No, that won't work either. getAttribute returns an Object. You need to cast it to a Boolean, and then test if this Boolean is true.

Comment: updated the answer again and tested on my localhost.

Comment: @KashifKhan.....i have written the following in login.jsp, please check it: <%HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);

if(session1.getAttribute("authenticated")!=null && session1.getAttribute("authenticated").equals(true))
{
   response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}   %> then in doPost of servlet i have written: HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); session.setAttribute("authenticated", true); M i right?

Comment: @KashifKhan it is working but if i am opening two login.jsp in two tabs of a same browser then if i am logging into one login.jsp and home.jsp comes but after that if i am clicking login.jsp on that 2nd tab then it is not going to home.jsp instead control is going to login.jsp but in 1st tab where i am already logged in there if i am clicking login.jsp then it is going to home.jsp but simultaneously 2nd tab box is not working. Any help friend?

Comment: yeah the code looks fine. make sure to check that session1!=null

Comment: if you login in fisrt tab, then refresh the second tab. it will work fine. but a more better solution is to use a filter in your web application to check weather a user is logged in or not. read here for an example of filter http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat.html....

Comment: ya i am taking a look in filter

Answer (score 3):

Make the login page/action check if the user is logged in, and redirect to the home page if logged in:

```
if (alreadyLoggedIn) {
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/home"));
    return;
}
```

But you should probably not have a link to the login page in the first place if the user is already logged in.

Comment: thanks JB....but what should i write in doPost of servlet?

Comment: I have link to the login page even user is already logged on. I should write home.jsp instead of /home.. like this: response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/home.jsp"));

Answer (score 0):

For your help i have written an example and executed the code in my machine.

In servlet page, in `doPost`:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
boolean isCredentialValid = validateCredentials(username, password);
String nextPage ="";
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
if(isCredentialValid){
    nextPage = "home.jsp";
    session.setAttribute("isLoggedIn", "true");
}else{
    request.setAttribute("error", "Either username or password is invalid.");
    nextPage ="login.jsp";
}
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextPage);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

in `login.jsp`

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isLoggedIn = "<%= (String)session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")%>";
  if(isLoggedIn === "true")
     window.location.href="home.jsp";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="Test" method="post">
    ${error}
    <br/>
     UserName : <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <br/>
     Password : <input type="text" name="password"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: i need to write this in login.jsp?

Comment: nope.. login page will be redirected to a servlet.. write in in the servlet because you cant validate the credentials in browser right.. as per i understnad you will need to contact database through servlet right.

Comment: login page will be redirected to servlet only after user gives his username and password , if he is already authenticated before then when he clicked on login.jsp link then instead of going to login.jsp page and then how login.jsp page will be redirected to servlet automatically?

Comment: updated the answer.. please check it.. hope everything will be clear

Comment: For your help i have written an example and executed the code in my machine, its just working as you are expecting.

Comment: ya thanks for your reply, but i am using method doPost method for login, is this the same above code applicable for doPost method?

Comment: yeah.. just change the "method" in form tag to "post" like method="post"

Comment: dont forget to mark the answer as accepted for the help of future visitors, if it solved your problem.

Comment: This answer is awful: JavaScript to redirect, scriptlet in JSP, GET for a login form, a String instead of a boolean to represent a boolean value... Everything you shouldn't do.

Comment: @JBNizet : When I created the form in IDE, it taken "get" method by default, i didnt bother to change it because i knew that the question raiser is using "post" and this is not the problem. I dont think there is any problem in redirecting using javascript here. I thought to use "<%= expression %>" instead of scriptlet so i used string instead of boolean as i did now, removed scriplet. I had already given lot of time to write the code and execute it and post here so didnt do fine tunning.

Comment: You just wanted to vote down so you did not because of any reason. This answer may not be the best but it doesn't deserve vote down because the answer is not wrong or irrelevant or something, it did help the question raiser and that you can find out by reading the above comments.